# Sorting a document.getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, object

Right now in my code I have a table being dynamically built and then the user enters some data into a field in the table.  Afterwards I'd like to present the user with the opportunity to sort the list based on that field.  What I'd like to do is use document.getElementsByClassName to grab all of the value fields and then sort them but maintain the object data so something like this.

```
var posts = document.getElementsByClassName('data');
posts.values.sort();  // I'd like to sort the array by the value of the html objects
for(i=0;i<posts.length;i++){
    //modify table order
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to convert the HTMLCollection to an Array first then sort.

```
var posts = document.getElementsByClassName('data');
var arr = [].slice.call(posts); // convert HTMLColleciton to Array
arr.sort();
```

EDIT: Sort takes a function as a parameter that will allow you to sort based on an array's property

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all elements on `posts` array are input controls having `value` property, you could simply do

```
var arr = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName('data'));
arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a.value < b.value) {
       return -1;
    }

    if (a.value > b.value) {
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
});
```

or even better (thanks @Phil)

```
arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.value.localeCompare(b.value);
});
```

Take into account that I'm doing an alphabetical sort. Feel free to do the comparison more appropiated for your scenario

Comment: AFAIK you can't use `sort` directly on a dom collection, don't you need to convert it to an array first?

Comment: @Rob M.: you may be right, I'm not very used to `getElementsByClassName` and assumed it returned an array. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: @RobM. is right. You can use the `Array.prototype.sort.call(posts, function...)`. Also, `return a.value.localeCompare(b.value)` is a simple one-liner

Comment: no problem, I would just update your post to be: `var posts = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName('data'));` or go with @Phil's suggestion

Comment: @RobM. actually, I think you might need `slice` to convert it to an array first because `sort` doesn't return

Comment: Alright I'm a bit confused now, the data fields are numbers that will need to be sorted by their numerical value, and I will need to use the parentNode property after the list has been sorted.  Is there a quick way for me to get that information?

Comment: @Tyler in that case, you'll probably want `return a.value - b.value` in the sort callback or maybe `return parseInt(a.value, 10) - parseInt(b.value, 10)` if you want to be extra safe (and they're integers)

Comment: @Phil awesome that works, now how can I go from this sorted array to the posts[i].parentNode?

Comment: There is a golden rule not to treat host objects like native objects, so don't pass an HTML collection to *Array.prototype.slice* as *this*. It works mostly, but browsers like IE 8 will barf (though it doesn't support *getElementsByClassName* anyway). Also, the collection is live so messing with it will be messing with the DOM at the same time.

Comment: @RobG there seems to be a lot of misunderstanding about what a *live* collection is. Messing with any DOM element reference will change the DOM. A live collection simply means you can add later elements that match the selector and the collection will update accordingly without having to re-run it

Comment: @Tyler each element in `posts` is still a DOM element so you can use whatever properties you want

Comment: @Phil Let me rephrase better.  I need to take the array of sorted elements so I can do a for loop again with the sorted version and grab the parent element.  Meaning if row 26's field has the lowest value then on i=0 we grab it's parent node first.

Comment: @Phil—yep, you can try to sort it all you like but nothing changes. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

document.getElementsByClassName will give you a **HTMLCollection Object** but not an **Array**, and HTMLCollection Object do not have sort method

So you should change it into an Array.

```js
var posts = document.getElementsByClassName('data') , arr = [];
for(var i = 0 ; i < posts.length; i++){
    arr.push(posts[i])
}
arr.sort()
```

Comment: What kind of data will be stored when I push the node on?  Just the name of the object and it's data?

Comment: The data you store will be the same as the node.